# ArcGIS for Javascript Template available?

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

ESRI has a stack of templates in the ArcGIS Online section. But when you download them it turns out that in order to make them run, you have to first create a webmap via their WebMap Viewer application. And even then the map that you then host only references the webmap application you create on the ESRI Portal.

Coming from a FlexViewer background where I could use the Viewer app to create an application and then all files and folders were generated locally and I could edit or tweak as needed I was hoping for something similar with the WebMap Viewer.

I am looking for a blank webmap using the ArcGIS API for Javascript complete with widgets, place to insert basemaps, operational maps, etc. Does such a map template exist?

Answer (score 1):

This question is a month old so you may have already found options. The [Configurable Map Viewer](https://github.com/DavidSpriggs/ConfigurableViewerJSAPI) (CMV) sounds like it may meet your needs. CMV is built on top of the ArcGIS API for JavaScript. It is open source so you can edit and tweak if you need something more than what can be configured within the configuration files. We have recently added a number of new widgets with more coming very soon. A good many of the users in our growing community are migrating from the Flex-based viewer and contributing in many ways to the project. If you do use cmv and apply your own edits/tweaks, I encourage you to contribute back as well.

Full disclosure: I am one of the developers contributing to the project and use it in my business to provide solutions for my customers. There is no cost for you to use CMV.